# In Elasticsearch does the Update By Query API increment an external version of updated documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

We are indexing `cars` documents in Elasticsearch with an [`external`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-version-types) version.

We are then sometimes updating the `cars` documents using the [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) and [Painless scripting language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html). The update request looks like this:

```
POST http://search/cars/_update/445398312253724778?routing=91e2c33a-52f5-43f4-b8c5-6fb5673ff6e0&refresh=true&timeout=1m

{
  "script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source.status != 'NEW') { ctx.op = 'noop' } ctx._source.transition = params.status",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "status": "OBSOLETE"
    }
  },
  "scripted_upsert": true
}
```

It seems that the version of the documents is not increased when using the Update By Query API. I also couldn't find anything regarding the updating of versions in the [Update By Query API documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

However, according to [Elasticsearch' blog post detailing Elasticsearch Versioning Support](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support),

> With every write-operation to this document, whether it is an
> index,update or delete, Elasticsearch will increment the version by 1.

I am confused now. Does the Update By Query API increment the `external` version of updated documents?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can use external versioning with update by query since the whole update runs inside Elasticsearch. How can you access and external version number that way? Would you mind showing the commands you're running?

Comment: @Val I have added the update request to my question.

Comment: It's not clear why you mention external versioning. Also worth noting, in case of noop, the version number is not increased. External versioning is only possible at indexing/update or delete time, but update by query can only use internal versioning, which means the current document version is automatically increased by 1 in case of successful update

Comment: @Val The documents that should be updated by this query have been indexed with an `external` version as described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-version-types I thought that this could effect the update request somehow (maybe the version wouldn't then be incremented?).

Comment: When you index a document with external versioning, you're only providing an external version number, that's it, ES will not do anything else than store the version you're giving it. The document itself is not flagged as being externally versioned. When updating a **single** document, you can again provide an external version number. But when updating by query, the only versioning that can be used is internal (i.e. version++), because the whole update process happens internally to ES, as you're not able to provide any external version number

Comment: @Val OK, thank you. If you convert your comment to an answer, I can tick it as the correct one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you index a document with external versioning, you're only providing an external version number, that's it, ES will not do anything else than store the version you're giving it. The document itself is not flagged as being externally versioned.

When updating a single document, you can again provide an external version number.

But when updating by query, the only versioning that can be used is internal (i.e. version++), because the whole update process happens internally to ES, as you're not able to provide any external version number